# Disabling access to admin pages during maintenance

Tags: 6, users, maintenance-mode

I need to do some maintenance on a website that is updated by a number of contributors, what is the easiest way for me to disable access to the admin part of the website while I'm working on it?

Comment: Which portion do you want to restrict ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are user 1, and that the contributing users all have a particular role; you should be able to just remove the `administer site configuration` permission from that user role whilst you're working.  This should disallow access whilst under maintenance mode.